# ReactJS sluggish with frequent updates to big DOM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We're considering React for a DOM-heavy project and want to figure out the performance characteristics of the virtual-DOM rendering approach.

One thing that concerns me is that the virtual DOM is recomputed in its entirety on every minor state change. I can see the benefits of this model, but in an application with lots of elements and frequent minor updates this results in a lot of overhead for something as simple as a 'hover' effect.

This for example renders a sequence of `N` divs and changes the CSS class `onMouseOver`. On my system it's getting pretty sluggish from around `N=5000` (http://jsfiddle.net/estolua/aopvp7zp/).

```
var D = React.DOM;

function generateItems(N) {
  return _.map(
    _.range(0, N), function (i) { return { id: '_' + i, content: '' + i }; }
  );
}

function toggle(x, y) { return (y && x!==y) ? y : null; }

var Item = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    var item = this.props.item,
        appS = this.props.appState,
        focF = this.props.focF;
    return D.div({
        className: 'item' + (appS.focused === item.id ? ' focused' : ''),
        onMouseOver: focF
      },
      item.content
    );
  }
});

var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () { return {N: 10, focused: null}; },
  changeN: function(e) { this.setState({N: e.target.value}); },
  focus: function (id, e) {
    this.setState({focused: toggle(this.state.focused, id)});
  },
  render: function () {
    var that = this;
    return D.div(null, [
      D.div(null, [
        D.span(null, 'N: '),
        D.input({value: this.state.N, onChange: this.changeN})
      ]),
      D.div(null,
        _.map(
          generateItems(this.state.N),
          function (i) { return React.createElement(Item, {
            key: i.id, item: i, appState: that.state, focF: that.focus.bind(null, i.id)
          });}
        )
      )
    ]);
  }
});

React.render(React.createElement(App), document.body);
```

Is there a way to make such minor updates more efficient without giving up on the nice declarative form or is React just not suitable on this scale?

Comment: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate

Comment: @MattBall like this? http://jsfiddle.net/estolua/po8pen3o/ doesn't seem to have an effect. Also I'm not sure how I feel about having to hard-code all possible state transitions in a much more complex real-world scenario.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a couple potential solutions that allow you to continue to use the nice declarative model:

#### 1. Use `shouldComponentUpdate`

When you have a lot of elements, `shouldComponentUpdate` can be an easy win. The example from your comment isn't quite right; instead, you want to see if any of the `this.props` values you care about are different from any of the `next_props` you care about (and the same for `this.state` and `next_state`. For example, to only re-render when the focus prop changes, you might do:

```
shouldComponentUpdate: function (next_props, next_state) {
  return this.props.appState.focused !== next_props.appState.focused;
},
```

(although this simple example doesn't handle the ID or handler changing).

While this is pretty manual, you can easily build abstractions or mixins that will compare objects (either shallowly or deeply, depending on the structure of your props) to see if they've changed at all:

```
var ShallowPropStateCompareMixin = {
  shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState) {
    return !shallowEquals(nextProps, this.props) ||
           !shallowEquals(nextState, this.state);
  }
}

var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  mixins: [ShallowPropStateCompareMixin],

  // ...
});
```

In fact, this is already implemented as [the PureRenderMixin](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/pure-render-mixin.html). You can see this working in [this example](http://binarymuse.github.io/react-primer/build/index.html?6) (note that other things can cause sluggishness with lots of DOM elements, including extensions and inline styles that affect the box model).

#### 2. Localize the state changes

Another technique you can use is to localize the state changes; in your example, the top-level application state changes any time each item is hovered or unhovered; instead, you could delegate this behavior to the items themselves (or some other container for the item). That way, only the individual container items will have state changes, and most of the items will not be re-rendered at all.

Another idea I haven't tried is to group x out of the n items together in a grouping component (say, n=5000 and x=100); then, only the grouping component that contains the item that was changed would need to update. You could use shouldComponentUpdate on the grouping component so that the others do not need to be iterated over.

Comment: 1) So in your case the `shouldComponentUpdate` method basically specifies the subset of the global app state that is relevant to items right?
That's a reasonable strategy but doesn't seem to improve things in this case because there is no state other than the `focused` ID.
As for the mixin, I would've expected that to be standard behavior, why would you want to re-render if neither props nor state has changed?

Comment: 2) moving the state to the items is interesting, it could be problematic if other parts of the app need to subscribe to this state, but it does indeed fix the sluggishness and runs smooth even with N=50K http://jsfiddle.net/estolua/o3omfmae/

Comment: @estolua Re: the mxin, JavaScript makes it very difficult to determine if something has changed, as changing a deeply nested object or a key in an array does not make `===` return false for the object or array. The React team opted not to make this the default in order to try to prevent subtle bugs.

Comment: Of the two localized state changes will perform much better.  You can also do this in situations where the data is managed elsewhere by using event emitters, where each component subscribes to an event name based on its props.

Comment: @estolua To propagate such things upwards you simply create a custom "event" property: http://jsfiddle.net/o3omfmae/3/ much like the default html elements accept (onChange, onSubmit etc). shouldComponentUpdate is actually completely irrelevant to the OP's problem and should be removed from the answer, it's all about handling state where it belongs.

Answer (score 2):

On my system 5000 is still ok, but do you really need to render > 1000 dom nodes in a real world scenario? If you care that much about performance maybe you could consider [Mithril](http://lhorie.github.io/mithril/). It too uses a virtual dom approach but is really small and fast.

Comment: Yea, virtual dom is the way to go for large DOM!

Comment: It could easily become > 1000 nodes, and they would be a lot more heavy than the light-weight divs in this toy example. The performance might turn out acceptable for desktop systems but then there's also mobile. It might be interesting to benchmark this kind of scenario against other vDOM implementations, will definitely check out Mithril and Mercury at some point.

Comment: @estolua often the best way to get performance here is by using the infinite table approach, i.e. only render what can be seen.  On mobile, you'd probably only be able to see 10 or so of these 5000 divs.

Answer (score 1):

If you add shouldComponentUpdate to the Item component it becomes a little faster. Since it only renders the Items that are changing. But is still seems a little slow with 5000 items on my machine.

```
var Item = React.createClass({

    shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState){
        return (nextProps.appState.focused==nextProps.item.id) || (this.props.appState.focused==this.props.item.id);
    },
```